# How to receive more than 1 message from an SQS queue in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a little problem receiving more than 1 message/line from my queue in `AWS SQS`.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import boto

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = '*****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '******'

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name='us-east-2'
)

queue_name = 'Messages.fifo'
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)
messages = queue.receive_messages()


for message in messages:
    print('Body: {0}'.format(message.body))
```

Any Help would be much appreciated as to why.
Thanks!

Comment: DO NOT POST CREDENTIALS ON STACKOVERFLOW! Please immediately delete that User and check that your account has not been compromised.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind for next time even though i am just playing with this system :P

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are "just playing". Somebody could take those credentials and create lots of servers on your account and you would get a massive AWS bill.

Comment: Ok thanks for answer! I will change this now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `receive_messages()` function takes a `MaxNumberOfMessages` parameter that defaults to 1 message. Therefore, you will need to ask for more messages.

However, the [`receive_messages()` documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Queue.receive_messageshttps://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Queue.receive_messages) states:

> **MaxNumberOfMessages** (integer) -- The maximum number of messages to return. Amazon SQS never returns more messages than this value (however, **fewer messages might be returned**). Valid values are 1 to 10. Default is 1.

Therefore, you might not receive the full quantity of messages on each call.

---

Example:

```py
import boto3

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='my-queue-name')
messages = queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10)
for message in messages:
    print(message.body)
    message.delete()
```

Comment: Careful: There is no guarantee that `receive_message()` will respond back with exactly 10 messages. It won't ever exceed 10 msgs, but it can send you less than that. In fact, in most cases, you will probably get back 1 message if the total no of messages in the queue is small. Better option is to use SQS Long Polling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code (from a larger example on [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/40a75de3f87ee5dcc43aae320b878fb199fc463b/python/example_code/sqs/message_wrapper.py#L120)) that shows how to receive multiple messages:

```
import logging

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

def receive_messages(queue, max_number, wait_time):
    """
    Receive a batch of messages in a single request from an SQS queue.
    :param queue: The queue from which to receive messages.
    :param max_number: The maximum number of messages to receive. The actual number
                       of messages received may be less.
    :param wait_time: The maximum time to wait (in seconds) before returning. When
                      this number is greater than zero, long polling is used. This
                      can result in reduced costs and fewer false empty responses.
    :return: The list of Message objects received. These each contain the body
             of the message and metadata and custom attributes.
    """
    try:
        messages = queue.receive_messages(
            MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
            MaxNumberOfMessages=max_number,
            WaitTimeSeconds=wait_time
        )
        for msg in messages:
            logger.info("Received message: %s: %s", msg.message_id, msg.body)
    except ClientError as error:
        logger.exception("Couldn't receive messages from queue: %s", queue)
        raise error
    else:
        return messages
```